# How to erase a section of a merged object in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

How can I erase the dashed red lines in picture below in Inkscape? This is my first try of using Inkscape:

[image: Example image from Inkscape.]

I tried to merge those two objects and then use the erase function but that only erases the inner rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `edit path` tool, <kbd>F2</kbd> or second icon in the toolbox panel. With this you can remove nodes, or delete segments between nodes (second and fifth buttons in the tool control bar)

[image: tool control bar]